# how to take backup of existing database in sql server and save as a script in TFS

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

How to take a backup of existing Database in Sql server and Save it as script in local or TFS?
I have 3 DB's under Production server to take backup

Comment: If we click script database as--> Create to--> new Query window, will it takes the script of Database with Data or only Database structure?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: I can see an mdf file and ldf file creation, so I guess with script is created with Data and its log file

Comment: Right it creates the files....but do they contain any data? Hint...do you see any insert statements??

Comment: No, I dont see any insert statements

Comment: So do you think you have data or not?

Answer (score 0):

The following Query generates BackUp `.bak` file of database.

```
BACKUP DATABASE 'DatabaseName'
TO DISK = 'D:\FileName.bak'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, to the Disk means, it is our local Disk or DB server Disk?

Comment: DB Server Disk (Server Machine File System) but not Local Machine.